# How do i add angled tube for cable and led

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, sculpting, lighting

How can I make a hole for a wire and led in a ready stl object. as in the example below. Can you share a sample video or source?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I just tried add tube in meshmixer but I can't adjust the angles I want. I wanted to ask to benefit from the experiences of the users here. I don't have much experience.

Comment: maybe try with a Boolean modifier?